# Javascript/JQuery - val().length' is null or not an object

Tags: jquery

I have the error `val().length` is null or not an object"  from code:

```
function size(sender, args) {

    var sizeVariable = $("input[id$='txtHello']");
    if (sizeVariable.val().length == 0)
    {
          args.IsValid = false;
     }
}
```

The error occurs on the "If" statement. I am trying to check if:

1. the variable exists
2. if there is something in the variable

I think the problem lies with point (1). How do I check if the text field exists (to hopefully resolve the issue)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can test if the input field exists as such:

```
if($("input[id$='txtHello']").length > 0) { ... }
```

If it doesn't, `val()` will return `undefined`.

You could skip immediately to the following:

```
if(!!$("input[id$='txtHello']").val())
```

... since both `undefined` and `""` would resolve to `false`

Answer (score 5):

Try `if (sizeVariable.val() == undefined || sizeVariable.val().length == 0)` instead. That way, it'll check whether there's a value first, before trying to see how long it is, if it is present

Comment: why does @BvdVen use a === and you use == instead?  Which is correct?

Comment: === is stricter and better in this case than ==

Answer (score 1):

is sizeVarialbe null when trying to check the length?

```
function size(sender, args) {

    var sizeVariable = $("input[id$='txtHello']");

    if (sizeVariable != null)
    {
      if (sizeVariable.val().length == 0)
      {
          args.IsValid = false;
      }
     }
     else
     {
       alert('error');
     }
}
```

Comment: `sizeVariable` will never be null. If the textfield doesn't exist, then `sizeVariable` will be an empty jQuery object, which is not null. The function `val()` will still be available on it, but return `undefined` so `val().length` will not be available.

Answer (score 1):

make your check like this

```
if (sizeVariable.val() === undefined || sizeVariable.val().length == 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried...?

```
if( sizeVariable.size() == 0 )
{
    args.IsValid = false;
}
```

Comment: Sorry mate, this seems to fail

Comment: Sorry, size() needs to be lowercase, seems to be the simplest solution to me though.

Comment: that checks whether `$("input[id$='txtHello']")` yields any elements. it doesn't check whether its `val()` contains a value, which was the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery you can use:

```
if( input.val().length > limit)
```

or if for some reason it didn't work you can use:

```
if( ( input.val() ).length > limit )
```