# How do you find the length of the $(xml) tag from an ajax response

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to find the length of the xml object that is returned from an ajax request and am trying to determine if the xml in the response is 0 or not.  I've tried to use $(xml).length, but it doesn't seem to be working.  It return 1 for length regardless of whether their was something returned or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is the way jQuery does the XML parsing if the content is an empty string or just the XML header, `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` then it creates an error response with an `parseerror` node.  I created an example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/magicaj/55HQq/1/

If you can control the content on the server then I would suggest always returning at least a response node with the status in it, and then check the child size of the `response` node:

```
<response status="success"></response>
```

In jQuery you can check the size using:

```
$(xml).find("response").children().size()
```

Comment: I figured it out see this article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4723025/javascript-jquery-val-length-is-null-or-not-an-object