# Input field value's length

Tags: jquery, html, input

Is there a way with jQuery to find out the width of text inserted in input field of type text? I need that info because I need to perform some work when certain with is achieved. 
Also it would be very helpful for me to find the jQuery event that is occurring when user is entering one more character in input field which will make the first character of the whole value invisible?

Please see example http://jsfiddle.net/J58ht/2/

```
<input style="width: 35px;" type="text"> <span></span>


    $('input').on('keyup',function(){
      var input = $(this);
      input.next("span").text(input.val().length + " chars");
});
```

Try entering characters 123456 in the input field. When entering char 6 the first char 1 will be invisible.

I need that event, when value overlaps input.

Comment: see this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4723025/javascript-jquery-val-length-is-null-or-not-an-object

Comment: Please read question the the end. But again it is my fault, I should write width instead of length.

Comment: If you're saying that you just realized that you've asked the wrong question, you should edit your question.

Comment: I am not saying that I asked a wrong question. I am saying that lenght  should not be seen as general notion not as property of char array.

Comment: Kindly 'close' the questions by marking correct answers. This is what people here like when helping others. It will help ppl with same problem to identify the correct solution :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can find the length of the value by using jQuery's [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val) method which returns the current value of a form element as a string. Then you can use the [length property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length) from that string.

```
$('input').on('keyup',function(){
      alert('This length is ' + $(this).val().length);
});
```

Here's a working example on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/J58ht/

based on your edited question it should be like

```
$('input').on('keyup',function(){
      var my_txt = $(this).val();
      var len = my_txt.length;
      if(len > my_constant_length)
      {
          var res = my_txt.substring(1,my_constant_length);
          $(this).val(res);
      }
});
```

Comment: you asked to find the length of the input and ..??

Comment: Yes but in context of visual size. Sorry for not being precise enough.

Comment: that means if some size exceeds it shouls be un visible..??

Comment: u mean the first character sholud be invisible..??

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the question with help of your code. Please see.

Answer (score 3):

**Try to use:**

```
var LengthOfText = $("#txtInputText").val().length;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$("#txtInputText").val().length
```

[**.length**](http://api.jquery.com/length/)

Comment: that fellow started playing with my answer :) :)

Comment: @Freelancer some people dont have any work.So they will time pass by doing like this

Answer (score 1):

You can use length

```
    jQuery(selector).val().length;
```

**Eg,**

```
      $('#id').val().length;   
      $('#class name').val().length;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var inputLen = $("#txtInputText")[0].length
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
  $("#target").val().length;
```

And remember `length` is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

```
var value = $("#textFieldId").val();
var fieldLength = value.length
```

This works.

Answer (score 0):

```
To find out the length of text you can use 

var len = $("#id").val().length;

$("#id").keyup(function(){
  var textLength = $(this).val().length;
  if(textLength > 15){
    alert('Length is exceeded');
    //Do ur stuff;
  }
});
```